# Display the data attributes from a joined query in twig

Tags: attributes, doctrine, twig, join

I am quite new to Symfony2 and Doctrine but I did some programming with PHP.
I have two tables:

```
Quotes:
id
quote
subject
auth_id
```

and

```
QuoteAuthor:
id
authorFirstName
authorLastName
authorLastNameFirstLetter
slug
```

I am running a query:

```
"SELECT u, a FROM BetterLifeQuotesBundle:Quote u u.auth_id a WHERE a.id = 4"
```

In this specific query the result has only one row (this author has only one quote).
Query is done using WhiteOctober pagerfanta for easy pagination.
I am passing the result to twig and displaying the quotes

```
{% for data in pagerfanta.currentPageResults %}
    <li>{{ data.quote }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

In this case the data.quote attribute will be displayed.

**The Question is:**
How to display the data attributes from the joined `QuoteAuthor` table? 
i.e `authFirstName, authLastName` etc.

I searched on the web and I cannot find any answer.
By the way – if in the Twig statement above I replace `data.quote` by `data[‘quote’]` it gives and error that “Key 'quote' in object (with ArrayAccess) of type does not exist”.

All the information I require is in that `data` as you can see in the dump info below:

```
object(BetterLife\QuotesBundle\Entity\Quote)[760]
  private 'id' => int 500
  private 'quote' => string 'An archaeologist is the best husband a woman can have; the   
                       older she gets, the more interested he is in her.' (length=108)
  private 'subject' => string 'Men and Women' (length=13)
  private 'auth_id' => 
    object(BetterLife\QuotesBundle\Entity\QuoteAuthor)[758]
      private 'id' => int 4
      private 'authorFirstName' => string 'Agatha' (length=6)
      private 'authorLastName' => string 'Christie' (length=8)
      private 'authorLastNameFirstLetter' => string 'C' (length=1)
      private 'slug' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'quotes' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[753]
          private 'snapshot' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'owner' => 
            &object(BetterLife\QuotesBundle\Entity\QuoteAuthor)[758]
          private 'association' => 
            array (size=15)
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[345]
              ...
          private 'backRefFieldName' => string 'quote_author' (length=12)
          private 'typeClass' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[816]
              ...
          private 'isDirty' => boolean false
          private 'initialized' => boolean false
          private 'coll' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[769]
          ...
```

Comment: I get what you are trying to say, but I recommend making your actual question jump out a little more.  Your question "how to display the data attributes from the joined ...' is right in the middle of a good size post.  Making it stand out will make it easier to answer

Comment: Thank you for your hint and I have now corrected the actual question.

Comment: I believe `data.quote` should work. Your `quote` attribute is private however, so do you have a `getQuote()` method in your entity?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that I have no problem displaying data.quote or data.subject. My problem is with displaying the data.authorFirstName (for example) from the joined table - QuoteAuthor.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you will need a `getAuthor()` method in your `Quote` class (which returns the value of `auth_id`) and a `getFirstName()` method in your `QuoteAuthor` class (which returns the value of `authorFirstName`).

You should then be able to get the author first name using `{{ data.author.firstName }}`.

I would suggest renaming the `auth_id` property to `author` so that the relationship between `Quote` and `Author` is easier to understand.